# No JQuery UI is working in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Had some jquery-ui elements working the other day, now I'm not sure what I did but none of the jquery-ui stuff is working now. In my Site.Master page, I have the following...

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery.timepicker-1.2.2.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.timepicker-1.2.2.js" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

So, for example, in a page that pulls from this master page I'm trying to bind a datepicker like so...

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="LocationMainContent" runat="server">
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
<h2>DaysOff</h2>
<div style="width:50%;">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

This isn't working. More info - I'm getting client-side errors below...

```
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentException: sys.argumentException: An element with id 'ctl01'
could not be found. Parameter name: elementOrElementId - ScriptRescource.axd?<gibberish>
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
```

I don't really see why it's failing on that line in the .js file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the link that McCheeseIt has posted below, for some reason, you must separate out the ending `</script>` tag. For clarification...

```
<script src="..." />
```

Does NOT work...

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

DOES work. If anyone has any inclination as to *why* this is, I'm interested to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

the "undefined is not a function" error is probably `.datepicker()` can you confirm your paths are correct here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.timepicker-1.2.2.js" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: I can confirm that those are correct, the .timepicker is different from .datepicker by the way, but those aren't working either.

Comment: So when I'm adding the <script> tag to my master page, it would only work after separating the ending tag from the opening tag. IE - <script src=... /> did not work, <script src=...></script> DOES work. How does this make sense? That fixed timepicker, datepicker still broken, looking into it, will update this if I figure it out.

Comment: If you look in the original question, I was ending the script tags in the declaration. Once I separated the ending tag out, then all my jquery-ui components were working. Seems weird to me, if anyone has any input on why that is, I'm interested.  
So, for clarity's sake...

    <script src="..." type="text/javascript" />
Does NOT work...

    <script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>
DOES work.

Comment: huh yeah a quick google and looks like you're not alone: http://ilminator.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-sys-argumentexception-an-element-with-id-form1-could-not-be-found/